# How to only download a library, outside of a npm project?

Tags: npm

I am making a script in order to compare 2 versions of a corporate library. In order to do this, I need to download 2 versions of the same library.

The thing is : I only want to get the npm library, nothing else, without having to declare a `package.json` and without getting warnings about missing dependencies.

Also, I download the dependency using `npm install` because I still want to use `.npmrc` settings in order to download this dependency.

So far, my best attempt is to create a fake `package.json` then running `npm install`.

```
npm init -y #Create a fake package.json
npm install @acme/mylib ${MYLIB_VERSION_1}
```

Also it downloads `tslib` which I don't need.

If I run `npm install` wihout a `package.json` file, the dependency is not downloaded or I don't know where. Other sources say that it should work without `package.json`.

How do I only download the library without other stuff ?

Comment: If you want only the content of the pkg(s), i.e. without their dependencies, then: **1)** Use the [npm view](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-view) command to get the location/url of the tarball (.tgz). E.g. Running `npm view eslint dist.tarball` prints the following url: `https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint/-/eslint-7.14.0.tgz`. **2)** Download the tarball using curl, e.g. `curl https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint/-/eslint-7.14.0.tgz > /some/path/to/eslint-7.14.0.tgz` **3)** To extract the tarball consider utilizing the tar command. E.g. `cd /some/path/to/ && tar xvf eslint-0.1.0.tgz`

Comment: Oops, given the examples in points 1 and 2, the last tar command would actually be `tar xvf eslint-7.14.0.tgz`

Comment: @RobC I though about curl but, as I am using a corporate artifact manager, I need to use `npm` because of authentication stuff contained in `.npmrc`.